# ionic - RXJS error : rxjs_Observable__.Observable.combineLatest not a function

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs, yarnpkg

with my Ionic 3.9 app, I get this error : `__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_rxjs_Observable__.Observable.combineLatest is not a function` when running `ionic serve` in the browser.

I had plugins error so I removed the node_modules, the yarn.lock, and I reinstalled every dependencies via `$ yarn install`.

```
ERROR TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_rxjs_Observable__.Observable.combineLatest is not a function
    at NgxErrorDirective.ngOnInit (ngxerror.directive.js:40)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:12369)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:13893)
```

Here's my config:

```
$ ionic info

Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.6.0
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.1

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.0.0, browser 5.0.4
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.2, (and 5 other plugins)

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 25.2.5 (/home/louisro/android-sdk-linux/)
   NodeJS            : v8.9.4 (/home/louisro/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/bin/node)
   npm               : 5.6.0
   OS                : Linux 4.4
```

Here's what `$ yarn install` gave:

```
$ yarn install
yarn install v1.12.3
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning angularfire2@5.1.1: AngularFire has moved, we're now @angular/fire
warning cordova-browser > path-is-absolute@2.0.0: This package is no longer relevant as Node.js 0.12 is unmaintained.
warning cordova-plugin-ionic > @types/cordova-plugin-file-transfer@1.6.2: This is a stub types definition for cordova-plugin-file-transfer (https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer). cordova-plugin-file-transfer provides its own type definitions, so you don't need @types/cordova-plugin-file-transfer installed!
warning @ionic/app-scripts > autoprefixer > browserslist@2.11.3: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.4: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.4" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning " > @angular/common@5.2.9" has incorrect peer dependency "rxjs@^5.5.0".
warning " > @angular/core@5.2.9" has incorrect peer dependency "rxjs@^5.5.0".
warning " > @angular/forms@5.2.9" has incorrect peer dependency "rxjs@^5.5.0".
warning " > @angular/http@5.2.9" has incorrect peer dependency "rxjs@^5.5.0".
warning " > @ionic-native/camera@4.18.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@ionic-native/core@^4.11.0".
warning " > @ionic-native/camera@4.18.0" has incorrect peer dependency "rxjs@^5.5.11".
warning " > @ionic-native/core@4.5.3" has incorrect peer dependency "rxjs@^5.0.1".
warning " > @ionic-native/email-composer@4.18.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@ionic-native/core@^4.11.0".
warning " > @ionic-native/email-composer@4.18.0" has incorrect peer dependency "rxjs@^5.5.11".
warning " > @ionic-native/fcm@4.18.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@ionic-native/core@^4.11.0".
warning " > @ionic-native/fcm@4.18.0" has incorrect peer dependency "rxjs@^5.5.11".
warning " > @ionic-native/geolocation@4.18.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@ionic-native/core@^4.11.0".
warning " > @ionic-native/geolocation@4.18.0" has incorrect peer dependency "rxjs@^5.5.11".
warning " > @ionic-native/http@4.18.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@ionic-native/core@^4.11.0".
warning " > @ionic-native/http@4.18.0" has incorrect peer dependency "rxjs@^5.5.11".
warning " > @ionic-native/push@4.18.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@ionic-native/core@^4.11.0".
warning " > @ionic-native/push@4.18.0" has incorrect peer dependency "rxjs@^5.5.11".
warning " > @ionic-native/splash-screen@4.5.3" has incorrect peer dependency "rxjs@^5.0.1".
warning " > @ionic-native/status-bar@4.5.3" has incorrect peer dependency "rxjs@^5.0.1".
warning " > angular-svg-round-progressbar@2.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@angular/compiler@^6.0.0".
warning " > angular-svg-round-progressbar@2.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@angular/common@^6.0.0".
warning " > angular-svg-round-progressbar@2.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@angular/core@^6.0.0".
warning " > angular-svg-round-progressbar@2.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "core-js@^2.4.1".
warning " > angular-svg-round-progressbar@2.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "zone.js@^0.8.26".
warning "angularfire2 > @angular/fire@5.1.1" has incorrect peer dependency "@angular/common@>=6.0.0 <8".
warning "angularfire2 > @angular/fire@5.1.1" has incorrect peer dependency "@angular/core@>=6.0.0 <8".
warning "angularfire2 > @angular/fire@5.1.1" has incorrect peer dependency "@angular/platform-browser@>=6.0.0 <8".
warning "angularfire2 > @angular/fire@5.1.1" has incorrect peer dependency "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic@>=6.0.0 <8".
warning "firebase > @firebase/storage@0.2.4" has unmet peer dependency "@firebase/app-types@0.x".
warning "firebase > @firebase/functions@0.3.3" has unmet peer dependency "@firebase/app-types@0.x".
warning "firebase > @firebase/functions > @firebase/messaging-types@0.2.3" has unmet peer dependency "@firebase/app-types@0.x".
warning "firebase > @firebase/storage > @firebase/storage-types@0.2.3" has unmet peer dependency "@firebase/app-types@0.x".
warning "firebase > @firebase/database@0.3.7" has unmet peer dependency "@firebase/app-types@0.x".
warning "firebase > @firebase/database > @firebase/database-types@0.3.2" has unmet peer dependency "@firebase/app-types@0.x".
warning "firebase > @firebase/auth > @firebase/auth-types@0.5.0" has unmet peer dependency "@firebase/app-types@0.x".
warning "firebase > @firebase/firestore@0.9.0" has unmet peer dependency "@firebase/app-types@0.x".
warning "firebase > @firebase/messaging@0.3.7" has unmet peer dependency "@firebase/app-types@0.x".
warning "firebase > @firebase/firestore > @firebase/firestore-types@0.8.0" has unmet peer dependency "@firebase/app-types@0.x".
warning " > ng2-charts-x@2.0.6" has incorrect peer dependency "rxjs@^5.1.0".
warning " > ng2-charts-x@2.0.6" has unmet peer dependency "moment@^2.18.1".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
Done in 72.88s.
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is an issue `Observable.combineLatest`. It's hard to assume without seeing to the code but more likely if you import Observable you also need to import combineLatest too like this

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/combineLatest';
```

Hope it works.

Comment: Everywhere in my angular components where I import rxjs/Observable I added the line to import combienlatest as you suggested, but the error is still here

Comment: can you share at least one of example of your combineLatest how are you using so I might get a clue, its really hard to predict like this.

Comment: I don't use it explicitly ! that's the thing. If you look at the error I get, it comes from ngxerror.directive.js, and actually I use the rxjs errors in html like this: ` <div class="form-error" ngxErrors="password" #passwordErrors="ngxErrors">
        <div [ngxError]="['minlength', 'required']" [when]="['touched']">6 caractères minimum</div>
      </div>
    </ion-list>`

Answer (score 0):

As yarn tell you: you have incorrect peer dependencies.

I see you are trying to install the `@angular/fire@5.1.1` package which require `@angular/common@>=6.0.0`.
This also meaning upgrading all your `@angular/*` and `rxjs` dependencies to 6.0.0 or more.

You also should notice that there are some heavy changes between `rxjs` 6 and the former version (your combineLatest error may come from here). You can also instal `rxjs-compat` to keep your code as is.

Hope it helps.

Comment: There's :"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.12" in my package.json so why would yarn try to install 5.1.1 ?  Note: rxjs-compat is already installed.

Comment: I can't updgrade to angular 6, because it's an ionic 3 app, which works with angular 5. What can I do ?